# Pandas group list of dictionaries that has a value list

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a two lists `first_list` and `second-list`, I'm trying to group them into one single list (`single_list`) using pandas,
this is my code:

```
first_list =[
  {
    "name": "maria",
    "code": "MI",
    "cmd_count": 6,
    "indice": 1728205,
    "deal": 82,
    "items": [
      {
        "name": "papiers",
        "cmd_count": 2,
        "indice": 5950627,
        "deal": 68
      },
      {
        "name": "pens",
        "cmd_count": 1,
        "indice": 6940663,
        "deal": 74
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "Uzuno",
    "code": "UZ",
    "cmd_count": 1,
    "indice": 3232,
    "deal": 125,
    "items": [
      {
        "name": "printers",
        "cmd_count": 1,
        "indice": 28159,
        "deal": 9440
      }
    ]
  }
]

second_list =[
  {
    "name": "maria",
    "code": "MI",
    "cmd_count": 10,
    "indice": 1728205,
    "deal": 82,
    "items": [
      {
        "name": "glue",
        "cmd_count": 2,
        "indice": 5950627,
        "deal": 68
      },
      {
        "name": "pens",
        "cmd_count": 1,
        "indice": 6940663,
        "deal": 74
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "Fanky",
    "code": "FA",
    "cmd_count": 2,
    "indice": 46.603354,
    "deal": 1.8883335,
    "items": [
      {
        "name": "paint",
        "cmd_count": 1,
        "indice": 15987563,
        "deal": 465
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "Kaily",
    "code": "KA",
    "cmd_count": 2,
    "indice": 45,
    "deal": 789,
    "items": [
      {
        "name": "books",
        "cmd_count": 2,
        "indice": 3578,
        "deal": 74153
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "Lina",
    "code": "LI",
    "cmd_count": 1,
    "indice": 709,
    "deal": 5555,
    "items": [
      {
        "name": "rulers",
        "cmd_count": 1,
        "indice": 98,
        "deal": 96
      }
    ]
  }
]
list_to_group= first_list + second_list
single_list = pd.DataFrame(list_to_group).groupby(['code',]).agg(
            name=('name', 'last'),cmd_count=('cmd_count','sum'),deal=('deal','last'),indice=('indice','last'),items=('items','sum')).reset_index().to_dict('records')
```

Th problem is with the `items`, how can i do the same, i mean group them by `indice` .

Comment: You can't really group them by `indice` because some have more than one, plus they are double-nested, making it hard-_er_ to handle with a simple groupby.

Answer (score 1):

As was pointed out in the comment, you can't really groupby this way. What I would suggest is to do the foolowing thing.

Start by making your lists in one single dataframe using the function I provide below and concatenating the dataframes:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(first_list)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(second_list)

df1 = flatten_nested_json_df(df1)
df2 = flatten_nested_json_df(df2)

df = pd.concat([df1,df2])
```

(Alternatively, you can do this:

```
list_to_group= first_list + second_list

df = flatten_nested_json_df(pd.DataFrame(list_to_group))
```

)

where `flatten_nested_json_df` is defined as:

```
def flatten_nested_json_df(df):
    df = df.reset_index()
    s = (df.applymap(type) == list).all()
    list_columns = s[s].index.tolist()
    
    s = (df.applymap(type) == dict).all()
    dict_columns = s[s].index.tolist()

    
    while len(list_columns) > 0 or len(dict_columns) > 0:
        new_columns = []

        for col in dict_columns:
            horiz_exploded = pd.json_normalize(df[col]).add_prefix(f'{col}.')
            horiz_exploded.index = df.index
            df = pd.concat([df, horiz_exploded], axis=1).drop(columns=[col])
            new_columns.extend(horiz_exploded.columns) # inplace

        for col in list_columns:
            #print(f"exploding: {col}")
            df = df.drop(columns=[col]).join(df[col].explode().to_frame())
            new_columns.append(col)

        s = (df[new_columns].applymap(type) == list).all()
        list_columns = s[s].index.tolist()

        s = (df[new_columns].applymap(type) == dict).all()
        dict_columns = s[s].index.tolist()
    return df
```

This will give you the following df:

```
index   name code  cmd_count        indice         deal items.name  \
0      0  maria   MI          6  1.728205e+06    82.000000    papiers   
0      0  maria   MI          6  1.728205e+06    82.000000       pens   
1      1  Uzuno   UZ          1  3.232000e+03   125.000000   printers   
0      0  maria   MI         10  1.728205e+06    82.000000       glue   
0      0  maria   MI         10  1.728205e+06    82.000000       pens   
1      1  Fanky   FA          2  4.660335e+01     1.888334      paint   
2      2  Kaily   KA          2  4.500000e+01   789.000000      books   
3      3   Lina   LI          1  7.090000e+02  5555.000000     rulers   

   items.cmd_count  items.indice  items.deal  
0                2       5950627          68  
0                1       6940663          74  
1                1         28159        9440  
0                2       5950627          68  
0                1       6940663          74  
1                1      15987563         465  
2                2          3578       74153  
3                1            98          96
```

after which you can aggregate:

```
df.groupby(['code']).agg({'name':'last','cmd_count':'sum','deal':'last','items.name':'last','items.cmd_count':'sum','items.deal':'sum'}).reset_index()
```

which gives:

```
code   name  cmd_count         deal items.name  items.cmd_count  items.deal
0   FA  Fanky          2     1.888334      paint                1         465
1   KA  Kaily          2   789.000000      books                2       74153
2   LI   Lina          1  5555.000000     rulers                1          96
3   MI  maria         32    82.000000       pens                6         284
4   UZ  Uzuno          1   125.000000   printers                1        9440
```

Comment: Is `flatten_nested_json_df` essentially the same as `pd.json_normalize(list_to_group, "items", ["name", "code", "cmd_count", "indice", "deal"], record_prefix="items.")` (where `list_to_group= first_list + second_list`)?

Comment: Yes, but it ensures that everything is unnested in those cases there might be nested fields.

Comment: @Timus Thanks for the comment. Added the shortcut by using addition of lists.